# grails - The requested resource is not available when adding new method to controller in interactive mode

Tags: grails

I am new to Grails, learning about its basics. One of the first things I did was to follow the presentation on https://grails.org/learn. According to that it should be possible to add a new method to a controller while the application is running in interactive mode (launched by the run-app target), and access that method as an action without the need to restart the application.

When I was trying to do so, I got an error message 404 from the web server with the explanation: "The requested resource is not available". The new method does work fine after the application is restarted.

I am using:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

$ grails -version
Grails version: 2.4.3
```

The steps I did:

```
$ grails create-app grailsapp
| Created Grails Application at /home/marci/grailsapp
$ cd grailsapp/
$ grails
| Daemon Started
grails> create-controller hello
| Compiling 10 source files

| Compiling 131 source files

| Created file grails-app/controllers/grailsapp/HelloController.groovy
| Created file grails-app/views/hello
| Created file test/unit/grailsapp/HelloControllerSpec.groovy
grails>
```

I implemented `index()` in `grails-app/controllers/grailsapp/HelloController.groovy`:

```
package grailsapp

class HelloController {
    def index() {
        render "index"
    }
}
```

Saved the file, ran the app:

```
grails> run-app
| Running Grails application
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/grailsapp
| Application loaded in interactive mode. Type 'stop-app' to shutdown.
| Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion:
grails>
```

Checked `http://localhost:8080/grailsapp/hello/index` with the browser, worked fine.

Now I added another method:

```
package grailsapp

class HelloController {
    def index() {
        render "index"
    }
    def somemethod() {
        render "somemethod"
    }
}
```

Saved the file. Grails seems to have noticed the change in the source code and recompiled the file:

```
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
grails>
```

Now if I try to access the new method by the URL `http://localhost:8080/grailsapp/hello/somemethod` from the browser then Tomcat says:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
```

Note that the message is empty. If I try to access a method that does not exist, I do get a message, therefore a different error. For example `http://localhost:8080/grailsapp/hello/doesnotexist` :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /grailsapp/hello/doesnotexist

type Status report

message /grailsapp/hello/doesnotexist

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
```

If I restart the application in interactive mode and try the `somemethod` action again, then it works fine.

```
grails> stop-app
| Server Stopped
grails> run-app
| Running Grails application
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/grailsapp
| Application loaded in interactive mode. Type 'stop-app' to shutdown.
| Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion:
grails>
```

Now `http://localhost:8080/grailsapp/hello/somemethod` return the response I expect.

My question is, should the new action be available without restart, as it is demonstrated in the presentation? Is this a bug in the release 2.4.3 of Grails? Or should I do something more to activate this feature?

Thanks in advance,

Marton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should the new action be available without restart, as it is
>   demonstrated in the presentation?

Yes.

> Is this a bug in the release 2.4.3 of Grails?

Yes.

> Or should I do something more to activate this feature?

No, you should not have to do something more.

The reloading agent should work when you are in interactive mode but apparently isn't.  If you file an issue at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS we can take a look at that.

Thanks for the feedback.